# I can't format my SD card

Tags: external-sd

I just inserted a new 16 GB SD card in my AT&T Galaxy S5. I'm trying to format it but it's asking me for a pin and I don't know what it is its not the last 4 of my phone number and it's not my last 4 of my ssn. Please help!

Comment: please update your post along with the screen shot where exactly the device is asking the pin.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest thing to do is to insert the 16GB SD Card into another phone, a digital camera, or a computer SD card reader, and format it there.  You'll get the job done faster than any other way.

If for some reason you are set on using a pin, you can try 0000, which works in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have to fill in is the last pin you used for your lock screen

Comment: Correct, it's the backup password you use if you're using the fingerprint scanner to unlock your device.

Answer (score 0):

New SD cards are not encrypted by default. If it is encrypted, look at the SD card's manual/white paper for details.
**But more likely I think it is asking for mobile's password** as you are trying to wipe off all the data from SD card.